# Can I capture whether a user cancels the warning when an alert is displayed when trying to close a browser tab

Tags: angular

In Angular 15 I have added an event listener for the beforeunload event and if the user is currently playing an audio file I display the usual dialog.

[image: prevent dialog]

I cannot find a way to capture whether the user clicks Cancel. If the audio is playing then I would like it to continue if they do cancel.

The reason for this is because I need to know if the user has heard the entire audio clip.

My code for this is the function handleUnexpectedPageClose which is run on page init

```
handleUnexpectedPageClose(): void {
    const pageCloseSub = fromEvent(window, 'beforeunload').subscribe((event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {

      event.preventDefault();
      
      // Doing this now as we dont know if the user cancels the close
      this.endAudio();

      return (event.returnValue = '');
    });
    this.masterSubscription.add(pageCloseSub);
  }
```

I use a masterSubscription on the page to do a clean up on destroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`onunload`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) event instead of `beforeunload` because this will guarantee that unload event is actually triggered without worrying about the Cancel button.

Comment: Of course :) doh